# AndEngine shows sprite as a white rectangle?

Tags: android, andengine

when I try to add a sprite to my scene (in AndEngine) and run the app in my phone, it shows only a big rectangle. My code is:

```
myTex = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
myTexRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(myTex, this, "menu_spr.jpg", 0, 0);
```

My image's dimensions are 424*424. And I tried using both of `TextureOptions.DEFAULT` and `TextureOptions.BILINEAR`. Is my image damned? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't say which version of AndEngine you are using, and you don't show all your code ... are you loading the TextureAtlas? Something like

```
myTexRegion.load();
```